# What are the published methods to smooth a time series of weights?

Tags: time-series, references, smoothing

I am looking for methods to smooth a time series of human weights, in particular I would like to know methods that are quoted or described in articles published in peer-reviewed journals. I am also interested in the value of the parameters, for example the bandwith in a kernel smoothing method or the number of days in a moving average filter.

For example I think that this article (which I have no access to) describes some smoothing method used by the authors:

[HELANDER, Elina, et al. Time-series modeling of long-term weight self-monitoring data. In: *Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society (EMBC), 2015 37th Annual International Conference of the IEEE.* IEEE, 2015. p. 1616-1620.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=7318684)

Comment: Exponential smoothing is a fairly popular technique: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing